# How can I find a list of Facebook users of my app by using FB API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to get two lists: 1. list of users that are using my app 2. List of users that are logged in. I'd like to store the its in my app's data base. What do I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: "List of users that are logged in" --- logged in where?

Comment: App users list: FQL: `SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user = '1'`

Comment: @zerkms Thanks! I meant logged into the app.

Comment: there is no such state "logged into the app". As long as users logs into your application - you need to track that manually

Comment: @zerkms Can I do the same thing using Graph API?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 1):

App users list: FQL: SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user = '1''